# Min/Max/AVG per day SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL table with: ID, DATETIME (timestamp), TEMP. Multiple record per day.
What is the SELECT command to extract min/max and average per day ?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `group by`, but you need to extract the date:

```
select date(datetime) as the_date, min(temp), max(temp), avg(temp)
from t
group by the_date;
```